# Delete duplicate point cloud of the same part

Tags: kinect, openni, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi;
I would to create a 3D map with Kinect, using PCL, I have two point cloud aligned and concatenated but their concatenation contains duplicate point cloud of the same part.
How  can I delete this duplication without losing data.
I really appreciate any kind of help !
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190778/delete-duplicate-point-cloud-of-the-same-part./) by [faty](https://answers.ros.org/users/20001/faty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How aligned, and what are your constraints on the output? That really makes a big difference.

If you're willing to lose some representational accuracy, you can run the concatenated cloud through a [VoxelGrid filter](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php), which downsamples the cloud and leaves only one point for every x^3 size cube (leaf). This is essentially what the octomap will do, except that the output remains a point cloud.

If every point is perfectly aligned with every other, which is extremely unlikely, you can insert all the points into a [Map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), using the x,y,z tuple as the key, and remove any points that double up on one key.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at [octomap](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap)? It can almost certainly do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [faty](https://answers.ros.org/users/20001/faty/) on 2014-08-21**:
thanks for your reply, but I'is not what I' am loking for. ^^